# Regex match if pattern is not after another patten - PHP

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to wrap an iframe object in a div class, but only if it isn't already wrapped in that div class. I'm trying to use a negative match pattern for that div class so preg_replace will not match and return the original $content. However it still matches:

```
<?php
$content = <<< EOL
<div class="aoa_wrap"><iframe width="500" height="281" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uuZE_IRwLNI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
EOL;
$pattern = "~(?!<div(.*?)aoa_wrap(.*?)>)<iframe\b[^>]*>(?:(.*?)?</iframe>)?~";
$replace = '<div class="aoa_wrap">${0}</div>';
$content = preg_replace( $pattern, $replace, $content);
echo $content . "\n";
?>
```

Output (incorrect):

```
<div class="aoa_wrap"><div class="aoa_wrap"><iframe width="500" height="281" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uuZE_IRwLNI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div></div>
```

I'm not sure why the negative pattern at the beginning is not causing preg_replace to return the original $content as expected. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: you shouldn't be using regexes for this. use DOM and xpath.

Comment: You're thinking of negative *lookbehind*, not lookahead.  But that won't work because lookbehinds can't contain quantifiers.  The previous commenter is right, this will be a lot easier if you use a dedicated tool like [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up trying DOM as suggested in above comments. This is what works for me:

```
<?php

$content = <<< EOL
<p>something here</p>
<iframe width="500" height="281" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/uuZE_IRwLNI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<p><img src="test.jpg" /></p>
EOL;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML( "<div>" . $content . "</div>" );


// remove <!DOCTYPE  and html and body tags that loadHTML adds:

$container = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0);
$container = $container->parentNode->removeChild($container);
while ($doc->firstChild) {
    $doc->removeChild($doc->firstChild);
}
while ($container->firstChild ) {
    $doc->appendChild($container->firstChild);
}


// get all iframes and see if we need to wrap them in our aoa_wrap class:

$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName( 'iframe' );

foreach ( $nodes as $node ) {

        $parent = $node->parentNode;
        // skip if already wrapped in div class 'aoa_wrap'
        if ( isset( $parent->tagName ) && 'div' == $parent->tagName && 'aoa_wrap' == $parent->getAttribute( 'class' ) ) { 
                continue;
        }

        // create new element for class "aoa_wrap"
        $wrap = $doc->createElement( "div" );
        $wrap->setAttribute( "class", "aoa_wrap" );

        // clone the iframe node as child
        $wrap->appendChild( $node->cloneNode( true ) );

        // replace original iframe node with new div class wrapper node
        $parent->replaceChild( $wrap, $node );

}

echo $doc->saveHTML();

?>
```